# Right-Bottom-Corner black colored on a layer list

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code for the style of my list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#444444" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="#2f2f2f" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="00dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I dye the right bottom corner black ?

When I add a new layer-list-item it only appears at the bottom of the last.

Here is an example what I want to do: 
[image: Screenshot from Connect-App from Garmin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />


<item
    android:bottom="-200dp"
    android:right="-200dp"
    android:top="250dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-6"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#edf0f9" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>


 </layer-list>
```

Try this one and chnage from degree ,pivot x and y

and one thing add this as child view and put both view inside framelayout